# On big switch/case function or multiple independent function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm building a to-dos app with React Native

And when I click on a todo, I have a component that opens where I can edit everything about it (hour, day, name of the todo, description, labels, etc..)

I'm hesitating between create a function for every properties or create one big function with a "switch".

I feel like one big function would make it more clear but I have no idea about the impact on performance and maintainability in the future.

So for example:

```
editName = () => {
  dispatch(..)
}

editDescription = () => {
  dispatch(...)

}

editHour = () => {
  dispatch(...)

}

...
```

Or

```
todo = () => {
  switch(){
    case 'editName':
      ...
    case 'editDescription':
      ...
    case 'editHour':
      ...
  ...

  }
```

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow, since answers will be necessarily opinion-based. This is a legitimate developer question, but I think it should rather be asked on the Software Engineering Stack Exchange, where [similar questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147214/refactoring-switch-statements-and-is-there-any-real-use-for-switch-statements-at) have already been asked

Comment: I think 99% of people go with Option A.

Comment: Many options here. Another might be dispatching a generic action of `patchTodo(id, {[fieldName]: fieldValue})` which would save you a ton of code and changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in the context of react-redux, typically you would go with option A. You make a function called `mapDispatchToProps()` and hook that with your connect() to the store. Performance differences are negligible in this case and its easier to maintain (just add and remove key-value pairs).

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
      editName: (args) => {
        dispatch(editName(args))
     },
      editDescription = () => {
        dispatch(editDescription(args))
     }

   }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchTorProps)(Component)
```

In Option B (Switch-case), there comes the issue of how you can access the `dispatch` method, since it is only available when you are directly interacting with your store. You cannot call `dispatch` from another event-handler. It is unclear how you would even be able to bind dispatch to the returned cases.

Your todo function will have to look like:

```
const todo = (dispatch, actionType, actionArgs) => {
  switch(actionType){
     case "editname":
        dispatch(editname(actionArgs))
  }
}
```

But at the same time, how will you pass in the `action-type` to get the switch-case to even work and what about the action arguments? Then going back to how you can even access dispatch outside of the store.

`this.todo(dispatch)` is not executable, dispatch is undefined.

This is a round-about way to do something anti-pattern, that only increases the complexity of your code, whereas Option A is very clean and easy to use.